# No such file or directory: '/home/gitlab-runner/.Xauthority'

Tags: gitlab-ci, pyautogui

I am trying to do testing of UI using pyautogui and pyvirtualdisplay.

```
import os

import pyautogui
import Xlib.display
from easyprocess import EasyProcess
from pyvirtualdisplay.smartdisplay import SmartDisplay
import cv2
import sys
python = sys.executable

window_width = 1200
window_height = 800

# PyVirtualDisplay
display = SmartDisplay(visible=False, size=(window_width, window_height))
display.start()

# PyAutoGUI
pyautogui._pyautogui_x11._display = Xlib.display.Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])

# Do your thing
pyautogui_window_width, pyautogui_window_height = pyautogui.size()
print("Screen size: {}x{}".format(pyautogui_window_width, pyautogui_window_height))

p = EasyProcess([python, 'script.py'])
p.start()
p.sleep(1)
x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image='g.png', confidence=0.9)
print(x, y)

pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
pyautogui.click()

p.stop()

display.stop()
print('>>> All done.')
```

On running this code, I am getting this error,

```
raise error.XauthError('~/.Xauthority: %s' % err)
Xlib.error.XauthError: ~/.Xauthority: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/gitlab-runner/.Xauthority'
```

How can I test UI in remote server with or preferably without display.

Answer (score 0):

The post is quite old.. but I will answer anyway.
I just managed to deploy a Tkinter GUI with X-Server
It took me quite a while...

**long story short:**
just create a .Xauthority directory in the clients' repository.

**elaborated:** 
you can take a look here at the Dockerfile:
https://github.com/DorinBe/PySurfs/tree/dockerize \

I used 'touch CMD /bin/bash -c "touch /root/.Xauthority && python main.py"'

to debug I used some 'ls -la' commands in the Dockerfile.
example:
CMD /bin/bash -c "ls -la"
pay attention that after the CMD command is used, everything else in the Dockerfile is ignored.

to enhance the debugging, you can skip the installations of the requierments.txt file. it helped me to print some 'pwd' and 'ls -la' commands to understand the paths and whether actions (like creation of directories) really occurred as I assumed or that there have been a problem and those functions were skipped (and sometimes, there were problems, that's why I disabled the interactiveness of the containers' console).

before head:
pay attention to the installations in the Dockerfile that are required, and also disable the option to ask for input from the user during those installations (everything is mentioned in the Dockerfile, just read it and you will find how)

it is not directly associated with git-lab but I am sure that these are quite the same.

I will be happy to answer further questions :)
Good Luck!